# Hadoop MapReduce alternative for batch processing

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, batch-processing

Everywhere is said that Spark and Flink should replace Hadoop MapReduce because they run better in interactive workloads and support streaming. However, what if I have only batch processing use case?

Are there any alternatives for general batch processing to Hadoop MapReduce? I really couldn't find any batch processing Big Data tool ( I am not counting Hive because it is SQL layer on MapReduce, and also Giraph, because it is specialized on graphs).

It seems like every Big Data tool is aiming for the stream processing and Hadoop is left alone as a batch processing tool. Is it true or are they any alternatives? How else can I do Big Data batch processing without Hadoop MapReduce?

Comment: I've never used Flink, but Spark is widely used for batch processing.

Comment: Yes, Spark and Flink can be used, but they also supports many other features that I will not benefit from. Is not there any other solution only for batch processing?

Comment: Which features of Spark won't you benefit from? Spark Streaming is just microbatching on top of Spark.

Comment: IMHO Spark is a lot more temperamental than M/R to make stable on production environments (neither is a cakewalk, but all thing being equal I'd personally prefer to maintain M/R for simple batch flows). The problem here is future-proofing. Consider looking into apache beam (https://beam.apache.org/) or similar APIs if you want to be execution-engine agnostic. Then you can use mapreduce today and migrate off it in the future if appropriate without code changes.